# SQLite Database error on Inserting values

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
12-31 23:21:15.285: I/System.out(1609): onCreate SQL
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS la_table (
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     suggest_text_1 VARCHAR(100),
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     test_value_1 VARCHAR(100),
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     test_value_2 VARCHAR(100),
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     test_type_1 VARCHAR(50),
12-31 23:21:15.535: I/System.out(1609):     suggest_intent_data VARCHAR(5))
12-31 23:21:15.545: I/System.out(1609): INSERT INTO la_table VALUES(1,"Sodium (Na)","310 - 330 mg/dl",null,“Serum”,"1")
12-31 23:21:15.545: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1609): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: “Serum”, db=/data/data/com.assistant.lab.royale/databases/la_db
```

As you can see I'm creating a table `la_table` and inserting cetain values. I'm getting this error `no such column: “Serum”`. I'm really confused. I'm trying to insert "Serum" into column `test_type_1` not `"Serum"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with your quotes. The `“` around `Serum` are not standard.

Try with single quotes.

`INSERT INTO la_table VALUES(1,'Sodium (Na)','310 - 330 mg/dl',null,'Serum','1')`

Comment: I can't do that, I need to use `'` in the values. How can I escape `'`?

Comment: Double them, for example the string `Can't do that` would be inserted as `'Can''t do that'`.

Comment: It turned out to be a annoying feature of OpenOffice. OO uses “ instead of " (I'm editing the db using OO). Just replaced them and it works now. I'll accept your answer because I saw it because of your answer. Thanks. By the way SQLite handles double quotes just fine.